# R-Missing Data Analysis-interpretation of plot made by extracat::visna

Tags: r, missing-data

I just used visna() function in extracat package to visualize missing data, but I don't know what does the blue cells mean? And how to interpret the bar chart on the right?

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(25,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))
# visualise the number of missings in cases using visna from extracat
extracat::visna(df2)
```

[image: missing data plot]

Answer (score 0):

The blue cells represent the missing values.

For your data frame this means:
variable x1 has all it's missing values at the end of your data.frame.
For variable X25 the missing values are distributed all over the data frame

The red bar below is the amount of missing values for this variable.
I think the bar char on the right is the amount of complete rows for the respective bin of data.

For nice missing data visualizations also take a look at the naniar package.
( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/getting-started-w-naniar.html )